# How to map 2 identical tables in Hibernate hbm file?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have tables like `Trade_PAC_UNADJUSTED` and `Trade_PAC_ADJUSTED`. Similary for other regions .The table structure is same and they all belong to the same `schema`. How do i map these tables. I don't want to duplicate the properties of the class entries in `.hbm` file. Also my `POJO` class will be same for all of them.

Please help.

Is it possible to have something like this :

```
<class name="com.Bean" table="TRADE" entity-name="TRADE">
<discriminator type="string">
<column name="PROCESSING_LOCATION" />
</discriminator>
<property name="..........></property>
<subclass name ="com.Bean"  discriminator-value="PAC">
<discriminator type="integer">
<column name="RUN_ID" />
</discriminator>
<subclass name ="com.Bean"  discriminator-value="1" entity-name="TRADE_PAC_UADJUSTED"/>
<subclass name ="com.Bean"  discriminator-value="2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" entity-name="TRADE_PAC_ADJUSTED"/>
</subclass>
</class>
```

But there is no way i can pass the table name within subclass ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new POJO object and ask Hibernate to save it, how will it know which of your tables it should insert into?  You will need something in your POJO to tell it which way to go.

You might be able to do this using a Hibernate "discriminator" to treat this as an inheritance scenario.